Row Num column group by ProductId in SSIS Script Transformation Editor
Can anyone please help me.
They are all from a single order. There are 2 products with 3 parts. Product 10 should have RowNum 1,2,3 on each row. Product 12 should have RowNum 1,2,3 on each row.
Instead I am getting RowNum 1,2,3,4,5,6.
My current codes in the script are the ff:
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private int m_rownum;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        m_rownum = 1;
    }

    public override void Input_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        Row.RowNum = m_rownum++;
    }
}

This is my result:



OrderId
ProductId
RowNum




1
10
1


1
10
2


1
10
3


1
12
4


1
12
5


1
12
6



How it should look like



OrderId
ProductId
RowNum




1
10
1


1
10
2


1
10
3


1
12
1


1
12
2


1
12
3




You would need to track what the current ProductId is and reset the row num to 1 when a new one is encountered.

Hi @RyanWilson you are right. I did the row count where the product id is and grouped them there! Please mark as solved!

Glad to help. If this question is no longer needed to help you with your problem, I would suggest deleting it. I don't believe this issue will be considered helpful to the community. Not to say your problem was not relevant, but as you are new, I don't want to see your post get down voted into oblivion.
